# htaccess mod_rewrite does not work + is it possible?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I've been trying for the past hour to rewrite the following url using mod_rewrite in htaccess.
Original url http://localhost/index.php?Part=main&page=download
Desired url http://localhost/index.php?Part=/Main/Download

I do remember from the past that htaccess didn't work on on my pc for some reason..
Platform: Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit.
Software: Apache - Xampp.

I also checked httpd.conf and I couldn't find anything wrong with it,it is set to "AllowOverride All"...
Any idea what's the problem might be?
And is it even possible to rewrite it the way I mentioned above (file.php?Part=/$1/$2 instead of file.php?Part=$1&page=$2)?

Thank you for your time, I really do appreciate it!

Pasted the following code in my htaccess and it has returned an error 500

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewriterule ^index.php?Part=main&page=download (.*)$ http://localhost/index.php?Part=/Main/Download$1 [r=301,nc]
```

If it can be done in PHP, please explain how.
Contents of index.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();
# Disable Notices

if(!file_exists('assets/config/install/installdone.txt')){
    header("Location: assets/config/install/install.php");
    exit;
} else {
    # Get Database Information
    require_once("assets/config/database.php");

    require_once("assets/config/properties.php");
    require_once("assets/config/afuncs.php");
    # Define $getbase variable
    $getbase = isset($_GET['Part']) ? $_GET['Part'] : "";

    switch($getbase){
        case NULL:
            header('Location: ?Part=main');
            break;
        case "main":
            $getslug = $mysqli->query("SELECT slug from ".$prefix."pages");
            while($fetchslug = $getslug->fetch_assoc()) {
                $slugarray[] = $fetchslug['slug'];
            }
            include("sources/structure/header.php");
            include("sources/structure/theme/left.php");
            include("sources/structure/theme/right.php");
            include("sources/public/main.php");
            include("sources/structure/footer.php");
            break;
        case "ucp":
            include("sources/structure/header.php");
            include("sources/ucp/main.php");
            include("sources/structure/footer.php");
            break;
        case "admin":
            include("sources/structure/admin/header.php");
            include("sources/admin/main.php");
            break;
        case "gmcp":
            include("sources/structure/header.php");
            include("sources/gmcp/main.php");
            include("sources/structure/footer.php");
            break;
        case "misc":
            include("sources/misc/main.php");
            break;
        default:
            include("sources/structure/header.php");
            include("sources/public/main.php");
            include("sources/structure/footer.php");
            break;
    }
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: You can, but don't need htaccess for something like this. It can be done with just php. mod_rewrite would be more like if you wanted `localhost/Main/Download/` to be mapped to `localhost/index.php`. In php, you could just explode `$_GET['Part']` on `/` and that will give you the pieces of the url from `/Main/Download`. mod_rewrite is more for mapping a non-existing file/path to an existing file.

Comment: that's true. i agree.

Comment: I apologize but I'm not really experienced with PHP (or any other programming language for that matter).
Can you explain it more clearly how to do it? I'm an amateur..

Comment: Can you please explain how I can explode the $_GET['Part'] in the existing code of index.php?

Comment: if you want to go to this route you can use $_GET['Part'] and $_GET['page']. when you use the php's explode() function (look it up, easy example are on php.net) it will take whatever you've got in the url and store it in an array for you to use later.

Comment: I tried looking it up, but as I said, I'm not a programmer, just a newbie, I don't know how to use arrays or how to handle/integrate it with the code of index.php that I've posted above.. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write in whatever url style you wish, it also has regex in which you can pretty much do anything.

Drop this rule in the .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewriterule ^index.php?Part=main&page=download (.*)$ http://localhost/index.php?Part=/Main/Download$1 [r=301,nc]
```

In addition, set:

```
  <Directory ...> 
  AllowOverride none
```

to

```
<Directory ...> 
AllowOverride all
```

If it's the opposite the settings in .htaccess file will have no effect, it'll look for settings in the httpd.conf file.

If you don't want .htaccess involved or having difficulties with it you can insert the rule directly into your virtualhost for an example:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName www.example.com
  RewriteEngine on
  rewriterule ^index.php?Part=main&page=download (.*)$ http://localhost/index.php?Part=/Main/Download$1 [r=301,nc]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.
Apache dropped a server error 500 o.o

Comment: that means you have an error in your .htaccess file. can you post the contents of your .htaccess file in your question?

Comment: is mod_rewrite on? check phpinfo() to see if you've loaded mod rewrite. 
Normally internal server error occurs when .htaccess has error or undefined code.

Comment: Yeah, I copy-pasted the code you wrote in your answer..
For some reason it does not work.
I'd like to not touch the VirtualHost for the simple reason that most webhost providers do not give permissions to access and edit it.

Comment: paste your .htaccess contents. im sure its something small.

Comment: You can't match the query string in a rewrite rule

Comment: Oh, umm... How can I do it then?
Sorry for all the trouble but you guys are helping me big time, thank you!

Comment: I think you can by adding QSA ("query string append"). Try rewriterule ^index.php?Part=main&page=download (.*)$ http://localhost/index.php?Part=/Main/Download$1 [QSA]

Comment: mod_rewrite is loaded according phpinfo()

Comment: ok i figured it out. there was a space in my rewrite rule. i've tested it on my machine, it works. this is the rule: rewriterule ^index.php?Part=main&page=download(.*)$ http://localhost/index.php?Part=/Main/Download$1 [r=301,nc]

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still doesn't work, I'm being redirected to Part=main even tough I commented the NULL case in index.php that redirects wrong requests to part=main...

Comment: Not sure how you managed to get that to work, anything after the `?` isn't even included in the string the regex of a `RewriteRule` matches against. It's stripped off and stored in the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule:

```
rewriterule ^index.php?Part=main&page=download (.*)$ http://localhost/index.php?Part=/Main/Download$1 [r=301,nc]
```

has too many spaces. Apache is kind of obtuse about how it parses directives, so when it sees a space it assumes a new parameter. So in your case, apache assumes that `http://localhost/index.php?Part=/Main/Download$1` are the rewrite flags since it's the 3rd parameter of a `RewriteRule`, and obviously, those aren't valid flags.

Additionally, you can't match against the query string in a rewrite rule, you need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable. You can then use the `%` backreferences to reference groupings in that match. Try something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Part=([^&]+)&page=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?Part=/%1/%2 [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out I appreciate it!
It doesn't work, I'm being redirected to part=main because it's null and default (sort of error 404 for the file index.php)

Comment: @CoreModule you sure you don't have something cached? That rule [works perfectly fine for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jD3tH.png) in a vanilla apache install and a blank htaccess file.

Comment: I'm absolutely positive.
I've checked in other browser, commented the redirection in index.php and still doesn't work.
If it's somewhat cached, how can I refresh it?